# I clicked on properties for the image, and added alt text when I click ok the image disappears and on save its come back in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I was updating the alt text in a Sitecore item. I clicked on properties of the image, and added 'alt' text when I click ok the image disappears and on save its coming back again.
As a developer I don't want marketers guys to see such absurd behave. Help !

I checked my templates and media library, things are looking fine over there.

Comment: I suggest you to write to Sitecore Support about your issue. www.support.sitecore.net

Comment: Thanks, i will do so but this is problem with only one of item and its subitems. others are working fine, i checked the workflow and broken links but didnt found anything such over there.
just trying to figure out for this unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Have you changed the "Shared" status of the alt field?

Comment: its unchecked throughout.

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: Nothing as such in logs.

Now what i was trying is to compare the base template of non-working item with a working one.

working one was having a base template name as 'image' in which there is a field with values 'alt' 'height' ' width', when i am assigning this base template in the template of non-working item its just freezing everything in sitecore leades to instance not found error.
i cannot add this 'alt' field explicitly because this template is base of other template where values are getting repeated in their fields.